# I want the auto generated key from firebase whenever i push data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All the methods i have tried so far are only returning me the parents key and not the auto generated push key.

```
String key = rootref.child("user").push().getKey();
newUser.setUid(key);
Log.i("#####",key);
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put(key,newUser);
rootref.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

here the `getkey()` is returning "user" to me whereas i want the auto generated key.Prior to this i have tried using a child event listener and the `listenerforsinglevaluedevent` but even these gave the same output.Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: calling `push().getKey()` will return a new push ID. If you're having problems getting that push ID while reading, add the code that reads to your question.

Comment: Thats the problem...I am not getting the new push id...i am getting the parent id which is user...I didnt understand what you meant, as soon as i add ann object with push i want the push id generated, and thats present in my code

Comment: I just ran `String key = rootref.child("user").push().getKey(); System.out.println(key);` and it prints `-KS4eeDhFqKcKO3oBy6-`.

Comment: Thank you....I'm so sorry... apparently when I built n ran the app the changes I made were not reflected,i reinstalled and then tried,it works

Comment: Good to hear that you got it sorted sharang.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking your code and don't see the setValue. This is the reason why getKey returns "user". It should be like 
`rootref.child("user").push().setValue(UserObject)`

try this! 
I use this code.

```
rootref.push().setValue(UserObject).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),rootref.push().getKey(),Toast.LENGT_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This will execute a new push(), so the key toasted will not be the key for thar UserData.